# Perl changes to array not persisting

Tags: perl, loops

I am making a simple IRC bot in perl, and i thought it would be useful to be able to add admins. 
So i have at the very top, declared this array, with a couple of users in. And this works great, the bot identifies me and opps me on entry.
I've declared the array like this:

```
    my @adms=('user@host');
```

However i have the bot running in a while(1) loop, so that it's active, and with a sleep. And when i attempt to run -adduser (which is insider this loop) the changes don't persist, i have read that this is normal behaviour within anything but a for() loop, but this is maddeningly unhelpful.

```
if ( $funcarg =~ /^-adduser (.*)/ ) {
    my $user = "$1";
    sendraw( $IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl $pn" );
    push( @adms, $user );
    my $p = join( ", ", @adms );
    sendraw( $IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl Current admins are now $p" );
}
```

How can i make these changes persist, am i able to do something to commit this change back?

Thanks

EDIT:
I've not made this clear enough. So i shall add more code and explanation in the hopes of clarification. Sorry for any ambiguity.

```
my @adms = ( "Ducktator", "System69", 'Ducktator@Duck.net' );
# It is a bit further up, but i thought to spare you the IRC connection code, as I took some of that from a public perl bot anyway.

my $line_temp;
while (1) {
    while ( !( keys(%irc_servers) ) ) { conectar( "$nick", "$servidor", "$porta" ); }
    select( undef, undef, undef, 0.01 )
        ;    #sleeping for a fraction of a second keeps the script from running to 100% cpu usage ^_^
    delete( $irc_servers{''} ) if ( defined( $irc_servers{''} ) );
    my @ready = $sel_cliente->can_read(0);
    next unless (@ready);
    foreach $fh (@ready) {
        $IRC_cur_socket = $fh;
        $meunick        = $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nick'};
        $nread          = sysread( $fh, $msg, 4096 );
        if ( $nread == 0 ) {
            $sel_cliente->remove($fh);
            $fh->close;
            delete( $irc_servers{$fh} );
        }
        @lines = split( /\n/, $msg );
        for ( my $c = 0; $c <= $#lines; $c++ ) {
            $line      = $lines[$c];
            $line      = $line_temp . $line if ($line_temp);
            $line_temp = '';
            $line =~ s/\r$//;
            unless ( $c == $#lines ) {
                parse("$line");
            } else {
                if ( $#lines == 0 ) {
                    parse("$line");
                } elsif ( $lines[$c] =~ /\r$/ ) {
                    parse("$line");
                } elsif ( $line =~ /^(\S+) NOTICE AUTH :\*\*\*/ ) {
                    parse("$line");
                } else {
                    $line_temp = $line;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

sub parse {
    my $servarg = shift;
    if ( $servarg =~ /^PING \:(.*)/ ) {
        sendraw("PONG :$1");
    } elsif ( $servarg =~ /^\:(.+?)\!(.+?)\@(.+?) PRIVMSG (.+?) \:(.+)/ ) {
        my $pn       = $1;
        my $hostmask = $3;
        my $onde     = $4;
        my $args     = $5;
        if ( $args =~ /^\001VERSION\001$/ ) {
            notice( "$pn", "\001VERSION mIRC v7.25 CyberBot\001" );
        }
        # Check for what the nick is being used
        if ( grep { $_ =~ /^\Q$pn\E$/i } @adms ) {

            #Now check for the vhost being valid
            if ( grep { $_ =~ /$hostmask/i } @adms ) {

                if ( $onde eq "$meunick" ) {
                    shell( "$pn", "$args" );
                }
                #End of Connect
                if ( $args =~ /^(\Q$meunick\E|\-bot)\s+(.*)/ ) {
                    my $natrix = $1;
                    my $arg    = $2;
                    if ( $arg =~ /^\!(.*)/ ) {
                        #Here we get to set the calling command
                        ircase( "$pn", "$onde", "$1" )
                            unless ( $natrix eq "-bot" and $arg =~ /^\!nick/ );
                    } elsif ( $arg =~ /^\-(.*)/ ) {    # @ changed to -
                        $ondep = $onde;
                        $ondep = $pn if $onde eq $meunick;
                        bfunc( "$ondep", "$1" );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } elsif ( $servarg =~ /^\:(.+?)\!(.+?)\@-(.+?)\s+NICK\s+\:(\S+)/i ) {
        if ( lc($1) eq lc($meunick) ) {
            $meunick = $4;
            $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nick'} = $meunick;
        }
    } elsif ( $servarg =~ m/^\:(.+?)\s+433/i ) {
        nick( "$meunick|" . int rand(999999) );
    } elsif ( $servarg =~ m/^\:(.+?)\s+001\s+(\S+)\s/i ) {
        $meunick                              = $2;
        $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nick'} = $meunick;
        $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nome'} = "$1";
        foreach my $canal (@canais) {
            sendraw("JOIN $canal $chanpass");
        }
    }
}
# This is where i have bot functions going on, and it's when i do this code below, it doesn't update the main @adms array, the change seems to dissapear instantly.
sub bfunc {
    my $printl  = $_[0];
    my $funcarg = $_[1];
    if ( my $pid = fork ) {
        waitpid( $pid, 0 );
    } else {
        if (fork) {
            exit;
        } else {

            if ( $funcarg =~ /^-adduser (.*)/ ) {
                my $user = "$1";
                push( @adms, $user );
                my $p = join( ", ", @adms );
                sendraw( $IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl Current admins are now $p" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that makes no sense. Maybe you're resetting the value of `@adms` inside the loop?

Comment: Can you explain this a bit better. You declare admins in an array, you add an admin in the array, and the next time you run the program, your admin list didn't change?

Comment: No, not the next time i run it, if i instantly after run --listusers it will read the default one, not with the new value in it. And no, i am not resetting it intentionally, is my decleration like above possibly doing so? In which case how can i make it start with default data otherwise?

Comment: are you using threads or multiple processes?

Comment: Have you declared the array again, inside the loop?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as, despite requests for more information, it hasn't been updated for twelve hours now. *"Questions seeking debugging help ... must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error, and* ***the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*** *"*

Comment: I was in bed due to my time zone. There is no need to get irratable.

Comment: And to answer the above, I declare the array outside of any subroutenes or the main while(1) loop, and i try to access and modify it from within. I will edit op quick with soem more code.

Comment: @user3407675 It's a good idea to come back and check your question a few times soon after you post on SO, just in case it's unclear and people need clarification. To answer your question: add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of your script, just beneath the shebang line (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/perl`), if there is one. You will probably get a number of errors, but this one is particularly relevant: `Global symbol "@adms" requires explicit package name at foo.pl line X. Execution of foo.pl aborted due to compilation errors.` You are declaring a lexical variable `my @adms` outside your subroutine

Comment: and then trying to use it inside the subroutine. This doesn't work because lexicals are scoped to the block they're declared in. You need to pass a reference to `@adms` as an argument to your subrooutine if you want to access it, e.g. `sub foo { my ($ref) = @_; push @$ref, 'foo'; }`, called like `my @adms = qw(foo bar); foo(\@adms);`

Comment: Moral of the story: add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of *every* Perl script you ever write. It will save you lots of time and headaches debugging.

Comment: You should put that as an answer so i can mark it as such. I understand what's going on now. But if i pass it to the function, or define it within, are the changes going to take effect again to the main array? Reading isn't the issue, it's writing to it which is.

Comment: "But if I pass it to the function...are the changes going to take effect on the main array?" You could always try it and see :) But yes, they will, thanks to [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). I would recommend reading the linked document thoroughly to get a good understanding of what references are and how they work; they are a very important part of Perl programming. Good luck with your program!

Comment: Please note that your code is not really an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)); it has a lot of extraneous material and is not runnable as it stands.  (Yes, it is hard work creating an MCVE, but you're also asking us to do hard work divining what is wrong with your code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forking and modifying the value in the child process, and changes made by the child processes cannot change the values in the parent.

Consider your function where you identify the problem:

```
# This is where I have bot functions going on, and it's when I do this code,
# it doesn't update the main @adms array; the change seems to dissapear instantly. 

sub bfunc {
   my $printl = $_[0];
   my $funcarg = $_[1];
   if (my $pid = fork) {
      waitpid($pid, 0);
   } else {
      if (fork) {
         exit;
      } else {
         if ($funcarg =~ /^-adduser (.*)/) {
         my $user="$1";
          push(@adms, $user);
         my $p=  join(", ", @adms);
          sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl Current admins are now $p");
         }
        }
    }
}
```

The parent process forks and waits;  the child also forks, and it exits.  The grandchild process then modifies its own `@adms` array, but no change it makes will be reflected in the parent process.